# ACCESS2010 Retrieve first name and the first letter of the last name

Tags: ms-access

I'm making a database to gather staff details etc. My Primary key needs to contain the first name + the first initial of the last name e.g. Jake Steel = JakeS

It is for MS Access 2010

thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad idea for a primary key. Why are you not using autonumber?